# Why there is no timestamp field in sensor_msgs?

Tags: ros, imu, ros2, timestamp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !

I've been looking into ROS2 sensor_msgs definitions for example sensor_msgs::msg::Imu and I see that there is no field for timestamp !

What is the reason for that ? In practice any measurement information must / could be associated with a timestamp for obvious reasons.

Even if IMUs typically don't provide built-int timestamps, the driver node who reads the IMU and publishes the IMU messages could attach a timestamp to the information.

It would make so many thing so much thing easier....
thanks,
g

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338345/why-there-is-no-timestamp-field-in-sensor_msgs-?/) by [gdebrecz](https://answers.ros.org/users/49380/gdebrecz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2019-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In `sensor_msgs::msg::Imu` there is `std_msgs/Header header`.

Inside  `std_msgs/Header` there is include `builtin_interfaces/Time stamp` which is time stamp.

The definition about  Imu you can see [there](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/81663c07b93889c3d0afda9b99cd5f1c7c98c1f2/sensor_msgs/msg/Imu.msg).

And the  definition about  Header you can see [there](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/81663c07b93889c3d0afda9b99cd5f1c7c98c1f2/std_msgs/msg/Header.msg).

---

Originally posted by [jufeng wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/49417/jufeng-wu/) with karma: 83 on 2019-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gdebrecz](https://answers.ros.org/users/49380/gdebrecz/) on 2019-11-22**:
Thanks a lot.... !

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-22**:
@gdebrecz: please mark the question as answered by ticking the checkmark (✓) to the left of the answer.